# No exact match found for this new user in SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, people-picker

I am having a SP 2010 server, with  default web appln - 80 port.
when i try to add users into the home members, i am getting the error

> **"No exact match found for this new user"**.

i dont have user profile service appln created in this single server /stand alone machine.

i even did try to add users in the central admin ->manage service account etc. but that also in vain. 
Is it mandatory to create user profile service appln for this  users identification>?

i tried to restart the sp admin service on services.msc console, but i got an error:
[image: unable-2-restart-spadmin-service]

how to resolve this issue?

server role :
  [image: server_role_APPLICATION]

Comment: is it single server farm or stand alone farm?

Comment: Server Role : APPLICATION.                                
   Sorry, i just checked in the registry , its not a  standalone server

Comment: check if this apply to ur sitution https://jkhk.wordpress.com/2009/09/14/no-exact-match-found-when-adding-using-from-different-domains-in-sharepoint/

Comment: Restart your server, then check.

Comment: Is it necessary that, i need to create a  user profile service appln in order to get the domain users recognized in PEOPLE PICKER , when trying to add those in home owners,members etc ?

Comment: any soln, steps to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your error with the SharePoint Admin Service is when you did this:

"i even did try to add users in the central admin ->manage service account etc. but that also in vain." I don't know WHERE you got the idea that this has anything to do with adding users. The Service Account for Central Admin is a SINGLE account that has Administration permissions to run SharePoint. You set it once when you install SharePoint, and you DON'T touch it again without a very good reason. I would be surprised if SharePoint works correctly at all, after doing that. You need to set the Service Account back to whatever it was before you changed it.

Now, your original problem, you can only add users who are in your Active Directory (AD) for your domain. (There are other sources other than AD, but I'm pretty sure you aren't set up that way.) You need to check Active Directory and see if the user exists. If they do, you should be able to add them. If not, they need to be added to AD first.